# UITextView consumes huge memory in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

The problem appears pretty straightforward but it is difficult to find remedy for it.
Each time I used UITextView on iPhone, memory usage shown in Xcode displays abnormally huge utilization. For example, a UITextView that contains a short paragraph (around 1KB) consumes around 17-18mB memory when I scroll it up and down. Not to mention large text amount like 100KB file which takes half a minute to load to the view.

Here is how I implement it in viewDidLoad()
I don't assume it has anything to do with the code because it is exactly the same issue when
I have a new UITextView created from the storyboard with default sample text inside.

I have an NSString that reads file content and make UITextView show the NSString as its text.

```
@interface FileContentViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fileNameTextLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *fileContentView;
@end

@implementation FileContentViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)displayFileContentInTxtView
{
    if (!self.fileData) {
        self.fileContentView.text=@"file is empty";
        return;
    }

    unsigned char *fileContentBuffer=(unsigned char *)[self.fileData bytes];
    NSString *fileContentString=@"";
    for(int i=0;i<[self.fileData length];i++)
    {
        fileContentString=[fileContentString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x",*(fileContentBuffer+i)]];
    }
    self.fileContentView.text=fileContentString;
    self.fileData=nil;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.fileNameTextLabel.text=self.titleLabelText;
    [self displayFileContentInTxtView];
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "reads file content".

Comment: Have you checking in Instruments that it is the UITextView consuming the 18MB of memory and not the entire app? And is this wired memory or something else?

Comment: The point is that the app always consumes more than 1000-2000 times the size of text in the UITextView. That is, if a have 1KB text in the text view, the app consumes 1-2MB mem; in case I put 100KB text, memory usage goes up to 200MB. There is nothing I can do in code I suppose except that I split file content into small slices of no more than 512B.

Comment: This is still a real problem in 2019!  here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59020919/294884

Answer (score 0):

try just having the UITextView display text instead of reading file content, you can do this with not very much code:

```
YourTextViewName.text = @"[put the text to display here]";
```

either that or you could try fiddling with voidDidReceiveMemoryWarning part of the appdelegate.m file

OR

you could try displaying JUST the file that you are pulling the content from and remove the code that pulls the content.

Answer (score 0):

This is very inefficient

```
unsigned char *fileContentBuffer=(unsigned char *)[self.fileData bytes];
NSString *fileContentString=@"";
for(int i=0;i<[self.fileData length];i++)
{
    fileContentString=[fileContentString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x",*(fileContentBuffer+i)]];
}
```

The reason is that the each invocation of `stringByAppendingString` allocates memory to create a new NSString object. So if your file has 2KB of size, you will be creating 2048 NSString objects, and each of these strings contains each time one more character, so you're routine ends up using n(n+1)/2 bytes without releasing it (that is around 1MB of memory for a 2K file), and this is without considering the NSString internal memory needs.

Try something like this

```
NSMutableString *fileContentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:2*[self.fileData bytes]];
for(int i=0;i<[self.fileData length];i++)
    [fileContentString appendFormat:@"%02x", fileContentBuffer+i];
```

Notice the use of `initWithCapacity`, this will optimize the memory allocation from the very begining, and avoids unnecessary re-allocation and copy.

Comment: Yes here is a performance issue and I have corrected it already. But this does not solve the UITextView memory problem.