# UITextView: Huge Memory Usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm encountering what seems like excessive memory usage in a UITextView. I'm loading a 50Kb ascii text file into an NSString and assign it to the .text property of an empty UITextView component in my app. This immediately adds more than 100Mb to my memory footprint (2000x the actual text content).

Is there a way (a property or conversion) to make the UITextView more memory efficient? I need the editability and scrolling of the contents, but it's plain text (not attributed) and I'm not using any complex layout or rich text features.

For context: I'm working in a memory-constrained environment (an audio unit extension) so every Mb of memory counts.

This doesn't seem to be related to the well-documented iOS11 UITextView memory leak, since I'm not releasing the component.

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Example" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
myUITextView.text = content; // this adds over 110Mb of memory usage for a 50Kb text file.
```

Comment: I did a test on `IOS 12`, using a `190KB` file containing random text, and I don't go past the 50MB mark. Are you sure `+[NSStringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error]` is not getting called multiple times? Also, it's not clear what version you're on - are you on iOS 11 or 12?

Comment: The text loading is not the issue: in the debugger I can see that the memory requirement doesn't grow until the NSString is assigned to the UITextView. I can also "generate" the string (instead of loading it) with the same result. This is on iOS12.

Comment: **This decade old problem w/ iOS seems to still be true in some cases!**

Answer (score 3):

**OP is totally correct!**

We found that if you add to a text view, in the "+=" sense, it uses insanely large amounts of memory.

We had a text view like this

```
 @IBOutlet var showValues: UITextView!
```

and it would display some lines (say, 10 to 100 or so lines) of text, each line just being an integer.

So I very simply "appended" the text each time, like this:

```
 latestValue: String = .. // something like "14.4 \n"
 showValues.text += latestValue
```

If you simply try this it adds about 1/2 mb every line!!!!!!!!!

Perhaps this is a plain bug in iOS?

How could it possibly be?  It's easy to test this!

Comment: Indeed, the problem seems to be not only when using "+=".  There seems to be many, many problems with both UITextView and UILabel, simply in situations where you often change the text.  Truly ridiculous.

Comment: You can very easily test this by nothing more complicated than just assigning the same short text to a UITextView (or label) a few thousand times.  This is insanity, Apple.

Comment: So in 2023, I am not going insane. The UITextView is still leaking memory. I just tried to load a 1.1 MB text content into the view and it would kill the app by hitting the MEM limit of device(iOS 17.0.3 - 14 pro) - 3GB. 

Strangely the issue doesn't happen on simulator (14 pro sim was at iOS 16.4)

Comment: Just to add more context, this issue happens when setting a font to the UITextView. If the font isn’t set, then it doesn’t have issues taking even 8 MB data as input and just using up 75 MB more RAM. The font being used also affects this issue. Ex: system font, SanFransisco(which is systemfont on iOS16+), etc have issues but using custom fonts, say, Helvetica-Bold etc doesn’t cause this issue. Also using any different scaling than default causes issue on both system and custom fonts. iOS font caching with scrollView(NSTextViewLayoutFragment) might be root cause as per xcode instruments trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is wrong really. You should not have 50kb worth of text in a single UITextView. What you should do is SPLIT up that text into pages. So you have multiple pages of UITextViews (reusable Viewcontroller).

**EDIT:** I have another idea  how about you use WKWebView for your editor. I am sure it will not lag. But u need expertise in CSS/HTML for that.

Comment: The UITextView is a code/script editor. So pagination would be both inconvenient and unusual, unless it can be made invisible to the user.

Comment: @BramBos what you think of my edited answer? I think it could work.

Comment: 50kb of text is nothing in a text view, and it has no relation to the problem.

Comment: if the UITextView is an input field, then user can indeed load 50KB file or even 1 MB file, the view itself should be scalable unless the full 50KB is on screen which will never happen as screen viewport is limited sized. This is ridiculous, that I spent 8+ hours thinking it was a memory leak from my app/design somewhere.